# Get all objects in a UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

Is it possible to get all of the objects of a UIView that I have passed from one view controller to another (without getting them from the parent's view controller)? Something like

```
NSArray *objects = [myView getAllObjects];
```

Comment: You would mean all properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subviews?  Yes:

`NSArray *subviews = myView.subviews`

[Apple Doc for UIView property: subviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW17)

If thats not what you meant, you'll have to clarify your question more...

---

**EDIT:** Some quick tips...

Remember you can do a `for(UIView *subview in myView.subviews) {...}` to easily iterate through them.

I *really* wouldn't recommend hanging onto to a pointer to that subview array (or any copies) beyond/outside of a single method.

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I literally searched about 20 minutes for that but couldn't find it. I'll check it out in a second and approve the answer if it works!

Comment: @IRLabs haha no worries.  UIView has a ton of documentation so its easy to miss. Updated answer with some tips.